# What is the verb for when a person criticizes you back instead of accepting the criticism?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

"When I critcise you, you start criticising me for something that's bad in me instead of correcting yourself. In this way, you think we are even and you don't have to correct yourself because I have some bad habits too."

Comment: "to critisize back" comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

This is called the

> [Tu quoque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tu_quoque) fallacy,

or the *appeal to hypocrisy*. It's an attempt to discredit a statement by saying that the speaker of the statement is guilty of the same problem.

As with all fallacies of irrelevance, sometimes the situation *is* relevant. This is  more familiarly referred to as ['the pot calling the kettle black'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_pot_calling_the_kettle_black).

Answer (score 1):

Or more modern name than one proposed by nene: "[whataboutism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whataboutism)".

Answer (score 0):

This could also be

> **ad hominem** ADVERB & ADJECTIVE
>   1 (of an argument or reaction) directed against a person rather than the position they are maintaining.

[Oxford Dictinaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ad_hominem)